# OData WebAPI 2 - Property method returns xml instead of json

Tags: c#, xml, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using OData WebAPI 2.
All actions (get entityset, get entity by id...) returns json
When I'm trying to get navigation property it returns expected json response.
But when I'm trying to get a property, the response is xml, which is not expected.

This is my controller code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the navigation property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetNavigationProperty([FromODataUri] string key) {
        ODataPath oDataPath = this.Request.GetODataPath();
        var navigationPropertyName = (oDataPath.Segments[2] as NavigationPathSegment).NavigationPropertyName;
        return GetProperty(key, navigationPropertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetProperty() {
        ODataPath oDataPath = this.Request.GetODataPath();
        var propertyName = (oDataPath.Segments[2] as PropertyAccessPathSegment).PropertyName;
        var key = (oDataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment).Value;
        return GetProperty(key, propertyName);
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage GetProperty(string key, string propertyName) {
        var entity = GetEntities(key, new[] { propertyName }).FirstOrDefault();
        var content = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(entity, null);

        // There are two System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions classes in two different dlls, we want the one on System.Web.Http.dll
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("System.Web.Http,"));
        var type = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions");
        // Method with parameter T, can't get it via GetMethod so we look it up as the only CreateResponse with 3 parameters.
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "CreateResponse" && x.GetParameters().Length == 3);
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(content.GetType());
        var response = generic.Invoke(Request, new[] { Request, HttpStatusCode.OK, content });

        // Return our response.
        return response as HttpResponseMessage;
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!
Omri.

Comment: I never tried Web API 2 with OData, but as far as I know, isn't the response format controlled by the `Accept` header sent by the client? Did you specify `application/json` for that header?

Comment: As far as I know, you're completely right.
Thing is, I didn't defined anything specific.
Just used my browser to test the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected as most browsers have application/xml in their accept header. For example, chrome sends this

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

OData protocol specifies that entities and collections of entities to be formatted as `application/atom+xml` and properties (complex, primitive, complex collection, primitive collection) as `application/xml`. All the above can and will be formatted as `application/json` on the json side of the world.

When you ask for an entity or a feed from the browser, there is no content type in the above accept header that the entity/feed can be formatted as according to the OData spec. So, we default to `application/json`. However, if you ask for a property (non-navigation), there is a match from the Accept header for `application/xml`. So, we send back `application/xml`.

Comment: Working with fiddler and sending the right accept header solved my problem.